# Using stdlib.h functions directly in assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, clang, x86-64

I have to do an assembly (x86) program that takes 2 long numbers from user input, adds them using a function and then prints the result. When I use the read syscall I get a string in ASCII hex code and I can't add the numbers like that. So I wanted to use atol that is a function of stdlib.h to convert the string to long. How can I include libraries in assembly? Is there another way to do this?

I have already tried:

1. `.file "stdlib.h"` (I have the lib in the current directory)

error: undefined reference to `atol'`

2. compiling stdlib.h with the .s file together using clang

error: stdlib.h: file not recognized: File format not recognized

3. making a .c file with only `#include<stdlib.h>` and compiling it with the .s file

error: undefined reference to `atol'

the comads I run are

```
clang function.s -c -g
ld function.o -o function
```

Comment: `stdlib.h` is a header file, not a library.  It merely contains function declarations.  Please post the actual code you tried because it should just work to use `atol`.  Also, what assembler do you use?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your complete code.  Post the code such that I can just copy it into a file and compile it to reproduce the problem.  Also post the exact commands you typed to assemble and link the code.

Comment: perfect that worked thank you

Comment: Just don't try to use `stdlib.h`.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment I'd check with the professor to ensure you are allowed  to call things like `atoi` in the C library. The professor may have expected you to write such a conversion routine yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linker complains that `atol` has not been found because it is a function in the C library, but you didn't tell the linker to add the C library to your program during linking.  To fix this, pass `-lc` to the linker to add the C library during linking:

```
ld -o function function.o -lc
```

It is very important that `-lc` goes last, otherwise the link might not work.  This is because the linker picks functions from libraries in the order you specify them.  When you specify `-lc` before `function.o`, it ignores the library as it doesn't need anything from it right now.  Then it sees `function.o` with an undefined `atol` and doesn't find a definition, causing the link to fail.

Lastly, when you use the C library, you should start your program from the `main` function (i.e. rename `_start` to `main`) like a normal C program and link through the C compiler:

```
clang -g -o function function.s
```

This causes the C library to be linked in automatically and makes initialises it correctly, preventing some weird bugs.  If you use any IO functions like `printf` from the C library, you should also end your program by calling `exit` so the standard IO streams are flushed correctly.

Note that the `stdlib.h` file is a red herring.  Header files are not needed for programming in assembly.  Their purpose is to tell the C compiler what the type of some functions are.  This is not needed if you do not use the C compiler.  The `.file` directive does not do what you expect it does.

Comment: `clang -nostartfiles start.s` also works: omitting CRT but including default libraries like libc.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, but then the libc may not be correctly initialised and you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: The OP is using `syscall` via the x86-64 System V ABI.  On Linux at least, a dynamically linked glibc initializes itself.  IDK about MacOS and its libc.  In general it's not *bad* advice to recommend using `main` instead of `_start` if you want to use libc functions.  But learning that libc can init itself with dynamic-linker tricks is pretty neat, IMO, and the point of writing asm by hand is probably mostly a learning exercise.

Comment: @PeterCordes But what if OP choses to do a static link?  Just because the glibc has a fallback for poorly constructed programs, doesn't mean that it's a good idea to rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You added a compilation unit (the .c file) to the project. This introduces the prototype of the functions in the included header file "stdlib.h". What you want is reference to that function. This should be introduced in the assembler file that shall use the function.

Adding a [extern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/extern-masm?view=vs-2019) statement to the assembler file should do the job. You don't need the C file with the include. You will have to add the corresponding library in the linker settings. But even if you successfully link an EXE file, you probably get a problem, since some functions in the stdlib needs an initialization. You must also call the C run-time initialization function.

Comment: That may work for MASM and NASM. He's using either `llvm-as` or `as` assembler (or a front end that uses them on the back end). With those assemblers any symbol that can't be resolved in the file are considered external automatically. What he is probably missing is linking to the C library.

Comment: How can I link it to the C library?

Comment: @juanpbm Pass `-lc` to the linker.  This links in the C library.